# Python run a function on main thread from a background thread

Tags: python, multithreading

Created a background thread this way

```
 def listenReply(self):
        while self.SOCK_LISTENING:
            fromNodeRED = self.nodeRED_sock.recv(1024).decode()
            if fromNodeRED=="closeDoor":
                self.door_closed()

 ...

    self.listenThread = Thread(target=self.listenReply, daemon=True)
    self.SOCK_LISTENING = True
    self.listenThread.start()
```

But self.door_closed() has some UI stuffs so that's no good. How do I call self.door_closed in main thread instead?

Comment: How about without Thread?

Comment: recv will block.

Comment: how does ipython other threads execute code run_cell on main thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it myself using signal and slots of the PyQt.

```
class App(QWidget):

    socketSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object) #must be defined in class level

    # BG THREAD
    def listenReply(self):
        while self.SOCK_LISTENING:
            fromNodeRED = self.nodeRED_sock.recv(1024).decode()
            print(fromNodeRED)
            self.socketSignal.emit(fromNodeRED)
```

.... somewhere in init of Main thread:

```
    self.socketSignal.connect(self.executeOnMain)
    self.listenThread = Thread(target=self.listenReply, daemon=True)
    self.SOCK_LISTENING = True
    self.listenThread.start()
```

....

```
def executeOnMain(self, data):
     if data=="closeDoor":
            self.door_closed() # a method that changes the UI
```

Works great for me.

Answer (score 2):

One thing to keep in mind is that each thread is a sequential execution of a single flow of code, starting from the function the thread was started on.
It doesn't make much sense to simply run something on an existing thread, since that thread is already executing something, and doing so would disrupt it's current flow.

However, it's quite easy to communicate between threads and it's possible to implement a thread's code such that it simply receives functions/events from other threads which tell it what to do. This is commonly known as an event loop.

For example your main thread could look something like this

```py
from queue import Queue

tasks = Queue()

def event_loop():
   while True:
       next_task = tasks.get()
       print('Executing function {} on main thread'.format(next_task))
       next_task()
```

In your other threads you could ask the main thread to run a function by simply adding it to the `tasks` queue:

```py
 def listenReply(self):
    while self.SOCK_LISTENING:
        fromNodeRED = self.nodeRED_sock.recv(1024).decode()
        if fromNodeRED=="closeDoor":
            tasks.put(door_closed)
```

Comment: This looks better. But, I am not sure about event_loop. How do I call this loop in main thread? Just "event_loop()" ? Won't it block the main thread?

Comment: Yes just call the event_loop function. It will block the main thread in a sense. Everything your main thread wants to do should be given to it as tasks in the queue. You will have will have to redesign your code in order to work like this. What are you using for UI? Usually UI frameworks have their own event loop threads which they use for updating the UI.

Comment: Using Qt for UI. Any loop in my main thread will end up blocking the UI. So cannot use this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `threading.Event()` and set it whenever you you receive "closeDoor" from `recv`.

For example:

```py
g_should_close_door = threading.Event()

def listenReply(self):
    while self.SOCK_LISTENING:
        fromNodeRED = self.nodeRED_sock.recv(1024).decode()
        if fromNodeRED=="closeDoor":
            g_should_close_door.set()

    ...

    self.listenThread = Thread(target=self.listenReply, daemon=True)
    self.SOCK_LISTENING = True
    self.listenThread.start()

    if g_should_close_door.is_set():
        door_closed() 
        g_should_close_door.clear()
```